# Python Socket ERROR serv_sock not defined TCP

Tags: python, sockets

can someone help me? 
This code gives me the error that serv_soc is not defined.

```
 # Create a TCP/IP socket
listening_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Binding to local port 80
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 1600)
listening_sock.bind(server_address)
# Listen for incoming connections
listening_sock.listen(1)
# Create a new conversation socket
client_soc, client_address = serv_soc.accept()
# Sending data back
client_soc.sendall("WELLCOME TO PINK FLOYD SERVER!")
msg(client_soc)
# Closing the conversation socket
client_soc.close()
# Closing the listening socket
listening_sock.close()
```

Comment: You are getting this error because you are trying to use non-existing `serv_soc` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, the variable `serv_soc` doesn't exist; you've never created it.

Perhaps you meant to say `listening_sock` there. Try this:

```
client_soc, client_address = listening_sock.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're `serv_soc` needs to be `listerning_sock`.

Comment: check the spelling!